# NextJS NextAuth Implementation using Custom Token Source

Tags: react.js, typescript, authentication, next.js

I am new to NextJS, it has somewhat been forced on me and the existing code was not authenticating correctly (after a period the site would hang - not return to login - this was due to the way we were using the refresh token). I decided to roll my sleeves up and re-write the way we were *trying* to do authentication following what was there (what was hanging off the session object and now required all over the code), whilst also re-designing the way refresh was done following [this](https://dev.to/mabaranowski/nextjs-authentication-jwt-refresh-token-rotation-with-nextauthjs-5696) and another few resources. This is what I have comeup with...

*_app.tsx*

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppProps) {
    const [interval, setInterval] = useState(0);
    return (
        <SessionProvider session={session} refetchInterval={interval}>
            <RouteGuard>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                    <RefreshTokenHandler setInterval={setInterval} />
                </ThemeProvider>
            </RouteGuard>
        </SessionProvider>
    );
}
```

where `RefreshTokenHandler` is

```
const RefreshTokenHandler = (props: any) => {
    const { data: session } = useSession();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (session != null &&
            session.token != null) {
            const clock = new Clock();
            const expiresDateTime = new Date(session.token?.expiresDateTime);

            const timeRemainingSeconds = Math.round((expiresDateTime.getTime() - clock.nowUtc().getTime()) / 1000);
            props.setInterval(timeRemainingSeconds > 0 ? timeRemainingSeconds : 0);
        }
    }, [session]);

    return null;
}
export default RefreshTokenHandler;
```

`Clock` is

```
export class Clock implements IClock {
    public nowSeconds(): number {
        return new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    }

    public now(): Date {
        return new Date();
    }

    public nowUtc(): Date {
        var date = new Date();
        return new Date(
            date.getUTCFullYear(),
            date.getUTCMonth(),
            date.getUTCDate(),
            date.getUTCHours(),
            date.getUTCMinutes(),
            date.getUTCSeconds(),
            date.getUTCMilliseconds()
        );
    }

    public nowISOString(): string {
        return this.now().toISOString().split('.')[0] + 'Z';
    }
}
```

Now, the main part is the `[...nextauth.js]` file

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                try {
                    if (!credentials) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    const { username, password } = credentials;
                    const token = await AuthApi.login(username, password);

                    const user: any = {
                        token: token
                    };

                    if (token != null && token.error == '') {

                        const userDetails = await AuthApi.getUserDetails(token.accessToken);
                        if (userDetails != null) {
                            user.userDetails = userDetails;
                        }
                        return user;
                    }

                    return null;

                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
        maxAge: Constants.AccessTokenLifetimeSeconds
    },
    secret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
    jwt: {
        secret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
        maxAge: Constants.AccessTokenLifetimeSeconds
    },
    pages: { signIn: '/login' },
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ user, token }: any) => {

            if (user) {
                token.token = user.token;
                token.userDetails = user.userDetails;
            }

            const clock = new Clock();
            const shouldRefreshToken = token.expiresDateTime < clock.nowUtc();
            if (!shouldRefreshToken) {
                return token;
            }

            token = await refreshAccessToken(token);
            return token;
        },
        session: async ({ session, token, user }: any) => {

            session.token = token.token;
            session.userDetails = token.userDetails;

            return Promise.resolve(session);
        }
    }
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);

async function refreshAccessToken(tokenObject: any) {
    try {
        const tokenResponse = await AuthApi.refreshToken(tokenObject.refreshToken);
        return {
            ...tokenObject,
            accessToken: tokenResponse.accessToken,
            refreshToken: tokenResponse.refreshToken,
            expiresDateTime: tokenResponse.expiresDateTime,
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            ...tokenObject,
            error: "An error occurred whilst refreshing token"
        };
    }
}
```

The `refreshToken` method returns an `AuthToken` object

```
public static async refreshToken(refreshToken: string): Promise<AuthToken> {
    const body: any = {
        address: 'token_endpoint',
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        scope: 'offline_access'
    };
    const url = `/authorization/token`;
    const authResponse = await AuthAxios.post(url, qs.stringify(body), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).then(result => JSON.parse(result.data));

    return new AuthToken(
        authResponse.access_token,
        authResponse.token_type,
        authResponse.expires_in,
        authResponse.refresh_token
    );
}
```

with `AuthToken.ts`

```
export default class AuthToken implements IAuthToken {

    public expiresDateTime: Date;

    constructor(
        public accessToken: string,
        public tokenType: string,
        public expiresIn: number,
        public refreshToken: string,
        public error: string = ""
    ) {
        const clock = new Clock();
        this.expiresDateTime = new Date(
            clock.nowUtc().getTime() + this.expiresIn * 1000
        );
    }
}
```

All of this seems to work as I want and due to the way I am embelishing the `session` object in the `session` callback

```
session: async ({ session, token, user }: any) => {

    session.token = token.token;
    session.userDetails = token.userDetails;

    return Promise.resolve(session);
}
```

I get all of the information I need in my pages and components. In the pages and components, I do

```
import { authOptions } from '../auth/[...nextauth]';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
...

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
    if (!session) {
        // Not signed in.
        res.status(401);
        return;
    }

    const userName = session?.userDetails?.userName!;
    const organizationId = session.userDetails?.organizationDetails.organizationId;
    const token = session?.token?.accessToken as string;
    const searchRegex = req.query.hasOwnProperty('search')
        ? new RegExp(`${(req.query.search as string)!.toLowerCase()}`, 'i')
        : null;

    // More code here ...
```

My question:

*Is this approach the correct way of doing this, are there any obvious improvements I can make, or glaring mistake I have made?*

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Related [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75393041/1014587), for context.

Comment: Where are the comments that were here?

Comment: [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. You should not expect them to be around forever.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/269301)